# How do I get this simple pytest fixture to work correctly?

Tags: pytest, typeerror, fixtures

I'm attempting to get a simple pytest fixture to work.

```
@pytest.fixture
def two_cities_wind():
    return {'bristol': [7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8],
            'bath': [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15]}
```

My test is

```
def test_city_with_high_wind_of_week():
    windy_city = weather.city_with_high_wind_of_week(two_cities_wind)
    assert windy_city == "bath"
```

I am expecting the fixture to provide the dict that should be iterable returned, but the test is throwing an exception.

```
        windy_city = ""
        wind_speed = 0
>       for city in cities_weather:
E       TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

src/weather.py:52: TypeError
========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
FAILED tests/test_zweather.py::test_city_with_high_wind_of_week - TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
======================================================== 1 failed, 10 passed in 0.49s ========================================================
```

The function under test is

```
def city_with_high_wind_of_week(cities_weather) -> str:
    windy_city = ""
    wind_speed = 0
    for city in cities_weather:
        highest_speed = cities_weather[city].sort()[-1]
        if highest_speed > wind_speed:
            windy_city = city
            wind_speed = highest_speed
    return windy_city
```

The way I am attempting this looks comparable with these examples
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-make-your-pytest-tests-as-dry-as-bone-e9c1c35ddcb4

Comment: You have to pass the fixture to the test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer supplied by @MrBeanBremen
I needed to pass the fixture to the test function.

The test should be called as follows:

```
def test_city_with_high_wind_of_week(two_cities_wind):
    windy_city = weather.city_with_high_wind_of_week(two_cities_wind)
    assert windy_city == "bath"
```